# Looking for a special synonym for "sharing"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

For sake of naming convention, I need a noun synonym to share that start with "ea" or "e". Is there any word that meets this constrain?

Comment: The word *sharing* is used in various ways. Which in particular were you referring to?

Comment: Export, exchange ?

Comment: @Lawrence, specifically idea sharing or script(code) sharing

Comment: Enunciation, perhaps. It would clearly be a sharing of the idea.

Comment: @Graffito, +1 for exchange

Answer (score 1):

The synonym closest to sharing and starting with "E" would have to be: Exchange

> The children were exchanging baseball cards to pass the time. - As a verb
>
> Can I offer you two dollars in exchange for the toy? - noun
>
> The exchange of equity between the two companies was unbelievable - noun

[Definition of Exchange](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exchange?s=t)

Thanks: Graffito for suggesting this in the comments.